# CSS issue with main wrapper div

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have no idea why the #mainControldiv div is not being enclosed by it's wrapper div.  Here is the html and css following it:

css:

```
*
{
 padding:   0px;
 margin:   0px;
}

div
{
 border:   1px solid;
} 

#mainWrapperdiv
{
 width:   1000px;
 margin:   0px auto 0px auto;
} 

#maindiv
{ 
 width:   850px; 
 height:   500px;  
 margin:   50px auto 0px auto;  
 border:   5px solid;
}

#mainControldiv
{
 width:   850px;
 height:   150px; 
 margin:   470px auto 0px auto;
 border:   5px solid;
 float:   right;
}

#moveablediv
 { 
  width:   50px;
  height:   50px;
  background:  lightgreen;   
  position:  relative;
  left:   400px;
  top:   200px; 
 }  

#centerPointdiv
 {
  width:   5px;
  height:   5px;
  background:  black;
  position:  relative;
  left:   22px;
  top:   22px;
 }
```

It should be pretty straight forward, yet i can't figure out why the mainControldiv does not show up within the border of the mainWrapperdiv, it's direct parent.  And can you also tell the logic, or the inner reason why it's not working as I'm expecting, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot end divs like that, even if a div has no content, it must have a closing tag:

```
<div></div>
```

So change you structure to be as follows:

```
<body>
 <div id = "mainWrapperdiv"> 
  <div id = "maindiv">  
   <div id = "moveablediv" >
    <div id = "centerPointdiv"></div>
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div id = "mainControldiv"></div>
 </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, your absolutely right.  Is that a XHTML standard or just a general HTML standard.  And under what topic can i find more information about these layout issues.  Thanks a bunch again.

Comment: `div` is defined the same way in XHTML as it is in HTML -- [according to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp). What you were attempting would be called a singular tag, and is only possible in certain situations. I was googling around myself and couldn't really find a decent explanation on the topic, so I cannot really help out in that regard.